# Why does the CSV file that I generate through php/mysql has errors written on it not the Data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have been trying to create CSV file through one of my sql tables(innoDB). Currently when i run the corresponding script which generates the CSV. It downloads a CSV file which has errors written on its cells as follows:

> PHP Warning: Empty row packet body

**Script:**

```
$host = 'localhost'; // MYSQL database host adress
$db = 'solodb'; // MYSQL database name
$user = 'root'; // Mysql Datbase user
$pass = ''; // Mysql Datbase password

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

require 'exportcsv.inc.php';

$table="report"; // this is the tablename that i want to export to csv from mysql.

exportMysqlToCsv($table);
```

**Function to generate CSV:**

```
function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'export.csv')
{
    $csv_terminated = "\n";
    $csv_separator = ",";
    $csv_enclosed = '"';
    $csv_escaped = "\\";
    $sql_query = "select * from $table";


// Gets the data from the database
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);
$fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);


$schema_insert = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
{
    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
        stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
    $schema_insert .= $l;
    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
} // end for

$out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
$out .= $csv_terminated;

// Format the data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $schema_insert = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
    {
        if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
        {

            if ($csv_enclosed == '')
            {
                $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed . 
                str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
            }
        } else
        {
            $schema_insert .= '';
        }

        if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
        {
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
        }
    } 

    $out .= $schema_insert;
    $out .= $csv_terminated;
}

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
//header("Content-type: text/csv");
//header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
exit;
}
```

**UPDATE** **:** This error comes when table has more than 10000 records otherwise it works fine. Can anybody tell why this happns for big number of records

Comment: its actully a mysql error

Comment: yeah how does it cause as far as you knw mate!!! some said me to check whether the table is myisam coz that would cause the error. but it is already innodb..

Comment: Why create the CSV so manually?

Comment: can u please give me a hint or two about the other way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small library I have used to fetch data to csv that has worked pretty well in the past. It uses the `fputcsv()` but it requires a PDO database connection (which is probably ok since the database connection you are using is deprecated). The `FetchTable()` function is the one that actually builds the csv and saves it to disk so techincally you could just copy out that code and modify it to plain procedural:

```
class   CSVtoZip
    {
        protected   $db;
        protected   $files;
        protected   $zipname;
        protected   $headerAddr;
        protected   $rootdir;

        public  function __construct($rootdir = '',$db)
            {
                $this->db       =   $db;
                $this->rootdir  =   $rootdir;
            }

        public  function FetchTable($table = false, $columns = array(), $filename = false, $db)
            {
                if($table !== false && $filename !== false && !empty($columns)) {

                        $filename   =   $this->rootdir.$filename.".csv";
                        $output     =   fopen($filename, 'w');
                        fputcsv($output, $columns);

                        $query      =   $this->db->prepare("select ".implode(",",$columns)." from $table");
                        $query->execute();

                        while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                fputcsv($output, $rows);
                            }

                        $this->files[]  =   $filename;
                        fclose($output);
                    }
            }

        public  function Zipit($zipname = false)
            {
                if(isset($this->files) && !empty($this->files)) {
                        $this->zipname  =   ($zipname == false)? date("YmdHis").uniqid().".zip":$zipname;
                        $zipper         =   new ZipArchive();
                        $zipper->open($this->rootdir.$this->zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

                        foreach($this->files as $filelocation) {
                                $zipper->addFile(basename($filelocation));
                            }

                        $zipper->close();

                        foreach($this->files as $filelocation) {
                                unlink($filelocation);
                            }

                        $this->headerAddr   =   "Location: ".str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"",$this->rootdir.$this->zipname);
                        $this->DownloadZip();
                        unlink($this->rootdir.$this->zipname);
                    }
            }

        protected   function DownloadZip()
            {
                if(isset($this->headerAddr)) {
                        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($this->zipname));
                        header($this->headerAddr);
                    }
            }
    }

// Accepts a root directory and database connection (PDO)
$csv    =   new CSVtoZip($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mydirectory/',$con);

// Fetch 'users' table and grab specific columns, name the file users.csv
$csv->FetchTable('users',array('ID','usergroup','first_name'),'users');

// Fetch another table with 2 columns, name it table2.csv
$csv->FetchTable('table2',array('ID','username'),'table2');

// Zip the file(s) into an archive called tester.zip, then download it 
$csv->Zipit('tester.zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a table locking vs. row locking deal with huge records/buffers and updates.

The easiest way to fix this is just switch it to InnoDB.

Locking the MyISAM table prior to doing this may also work, give 'er a go.

Edit: I derped out, just try locking it so you're the only one who is accessing it when you're dumping it.